# Autoscroll HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, animation, horizontalscrollview

I have a bunch of `EditText`s placed inside a `HorizontalScrollView`. However, when the activity loads, I just want the `EditText`s to be automatically scrolling from right to left the entire time. How would I go about this?

Comment: This question lacks information.

Answer (score 0):

Check my old question about somthing like this maybe help you :

[How to scroll horizontal RecyclerView programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035427/how-to-scroll-horizontal-recyclerview-programmatically)