# create horizontal Recycler view with left right pagination

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to create horizontal Recycler view with left right pagination like below image :

[image] 
Thanks in advance

Comment: you can achieve this 'carousel-layout-with-viewpager'
http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/06/carousel-layout-with-viewpager-in.html

Comment: My issue is pagination I'm currently trying above library

Comment: which library you are using

Comment: carousellayoutmanager library
 compile 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1'

Comment: try this http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/06/carousel-layout-with-viewpager-in.html

Comment: @NileshRathod You can refer this link what you need exactly https://github.com/RameshBhupathi/RecyclerViewWithLeftAndRightArrowsExample

Answer (score 0):

using Linear Layout Manager You can manage the gravity of recyclerview

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

Comment: and what should about those two buttons

Comment: And what about display item zooming..?

Comment: @NileshRathod Sorry but for your all question you can ask a new question.

Comment: didn't require at this moment

Comment: OK then let's end discussion here

Comment: Thanks @PriteshVadhiya I am new in android so can u send any demo or snippet for change item position from my activity?? because i stuck on that pagination

Comment: @SumitBandekar your welcome, this link will be helpful for scrolling https://stackoverflow.com/a/32145850/8164071

Comment: @NileshRathod You can refer this link what you need exactly https://github.com/RameshBhupathi/RecyclerViewWithLeftAndRightArrowsExample