# Scrolling recyclerview using buttons right and left

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scroll

I want to use right and left buttons to scroll items with like 10 items

I tried to use scrollBy but it did not work

Here is my Layout Image.

[image: i want to use right and left buttons to scroll]
I want to be able to scroll right and left

Comment: please have to look my answer

Comment: Did you forget to post your code?

Answer (score 3):

You can use for **Next button:**

```
mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() + 1);
```

And for **Previous Button:**

```
mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() - 1);
```

Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035427/how-to-scroll-horizontal-recyclerview-programmatically)

Comment: this must be the accepted answer...you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

You can have a variable that tracks the current displayed position of the RecyclerView, named it "currentPosition" in below snippets

Then increment it if you want to navigate to the next item as follows:

```
private void scrollToNext() {
    if ((recyclerView.getLayoutManager()) != null) {
        ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(currentPosition++, 0);
    }
}
```

You can use `RelativeLayout` or the custom layout instead of `LinearLayout`; according to what you're using in your `RecyclerView`

Similarly, decrement it if you want the previous one

```
private void scrollToPrevious() {
    if ((recyclerView.getLayoutManager()) != null) {
        ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(currentPosition--, 0);
    }
}
```